# Shortest path in dags: Part 1/3 - the graph data structure

Tags: java, graph

[Part 2/3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278188/shortest-path-in-dags-part-2-3-the-preprocessing-and-shortest-path-algorithms)

[Part 3/3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278208/shortest-path-in-dags-part-3-3-the-demo-benchmark)

I have [this library](https://github.com/coderodde/CR.DagSP) for performing shortest path queries on dags (directed acyclic graphs). This post presents the graph data structure:

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class defines the API for graph data structures. The actual nodes are 
 * represented as objects of type {@link Integer}. The client programmer should 
 * always be able to map the nodes to domain specific objects. 
 * <p>
 * Not only the query methods return a boolean value, but any other method
 * returns a boolean value indicating whether the structure of the graph has 
 * changed.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Jul 18, 2022)
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 10, 2016)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 10, 2016)
 */
public abstract class AbstractGraph {

    /**
     * This field caches the amount of changes made to this graph. This is used
     * for keeping track whether the structure of the graph has changed since 
     * the previous check of the modification count. Adding or removing a node
     * contributes one unit to the counter, and adding or removing or updating 
     * an edge contributes one unit as well. Note, that if we remove a node that
     * has incident edges to it, the counter will reflect the removal of the 
     * edges as well.
     */
    protected long modificationCount;

    /**
     * Caches the number of edges in this graph.
     */
    protected int edges;

    /**
     * The set of graph topology listeners.
     */
    protected final Set<GraphTopologyListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * Returns the number of nodes in this graph.
     * 
     * @return the size of this graph. 
     */
    public abstract int size();

    /**
     * Returns the number of edges in this graph.
     * 
     * @return the number of edges. 
     */
    public int getNumberOfEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the modification count of this graph.
     * @return the modification count of this graph.
     */
    public long getModificationCount() {
        return modificationCount;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the node {@code node} to this graph.
     * 
     * @param node the node to add.
     * @return {@code true} if the structure of this graph has changed, which is
     *         the same as that the added node was not present in the graph.
     */
    public abstract boolean addNode(Integer node);

    /**
     * Checks whether the given node is present in this graph.
     * 
     * @param node the query node.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the query node is in this graph.
     */
    public abstract boolean hasNode(Integer node);

    /**
     * If {@code node} is present in this graph, removes all edges incident on
     * it.
     * 
     * @param node the node to clear.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the node {@code node} had at least 
     *         one incident edge and, thus, the structure of the graph changed.
     */
    public abstract boolean clearNode(Integer node);

    /**
     * Removes the argument node from this graph.
     * 
     * @param node the node to remove.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the node was present in the graph 
     *         which means that the structure of the graph has changed.
     */
    public abstract boolean removeNode(Integer node);

    /**
     * Creates an edge between {@code tailNode} and {@code headNode} with weight 
     ' {@code weight}. It depends on the concrete implementation of this
     * abstract class whether the edge {@code (tailNode, headNode)} is directed
     * or undirected.
     * <p>
     * If some of the input nodes are not present in this graph, they will be 
     * created silently.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the edge.
     * @param weight the weight of the edge.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the edge was not present in the 
     *         graph, or the weight of the edge has changed.
     */
    public abstract boolean addEdge(Integer tailNode, 
                                    Integer headNode, 
                                    double weight);

    /**
     * Creates an edge between {@code tailNodeId} and {@code headNodeId} with
     * the default weight of 1.0. This method is a shortcut for constructing
     * (virtually) unweighted graphs.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the edge.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the edge was not present in the
     *         graph, or the weight of the edge has changed.
     */
    public boolean addEdge(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode) {
        return addEdge(tailNode, headNode, 1.0);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether this graph contains an edge
     * from {@code tailNode} to {@code headNode}. 
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the query edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the query edge.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the query edge is in this graph.
     */
    public abstract boolean hasEdge(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode);

    /**
     * Returns the weight of the edge {@code (tailNode, headNode)}. If the
     * query edge does not exist, returns {@link java.lang.Double#NaN}.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the query edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the query edge.
     * @return the weight of the edge.
     */
    public abstract double getEdgeWeight(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode);

    /**
     * Removes the edge from {@code tailNode} and {@code headNode}.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the edge to remove.
     * @param headNode the head node of the edge to remove.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the target edge was in this graph,
     *         and thus is removed.
     */
    public abstract boolean removeEdge(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode);

    /**
     * Returns the set of all nodes that are children of the node 
     * {@code node}. It depends on the actual graph implementation what is 
     * understood by the term <i>child</i>. In unweighted graphs, every child 
     * is also a parent of a node, which is not necessarily true in directed 
     * graphs.
     * 
     * @param node the query node.
     * @return set of nodes that are children of the argument node.
     */
    public abstract Set<Integer> getChildrenOf(Integer node);

    /**
     * Returns the set of all nodes that are parents of the node {@code node}.
     * 
     * @see #getChildrenOf(Integer) 
     * @param node the query node.
     * @return set of nodes that are parent of the argument node.
     */
    public abstract Set<Integer> getParentsOf(Integer node);

    /**
     * Returns the set of all nodes stored in this graph.
     * 
     * @return the set of all nodes.
     */
    public abstract Set<Integer> getAllNodes();

    /**
     * Removes all nodes and edges from this graph.
     */
    public abstract void clear();

    /**
     * Adds a listener to this graph.
     * 
     * @param listener the listener to add.
     */
    public void addGraphTopologyListener(GraphTopologyListener listener) {
        listeners.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listener));
    }

    /**
     * Removes a listener from this graph.
     * 
     * @param listener the listener to remove.
     */
    public void removeGraphTopologyListener(GraphTopologyListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onAddNode} message to all the listeners.
     * @param node 
     */
    protected void callListenersOnAddNode(Integer node) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onAddNode(node);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onAddEdge} message to all the listeners.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the added edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the added edge.
     * @param weight the weight of the added edge.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnAddEdge(Integer tailNode, 
                                          Integer headNode, 
                                          double weight) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onAddEdge(tailNode, headNode, weight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onUpdateEdgeWeight} message to all the listeners.
     * 
     * @param tailNode the tail node of the updated edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the updated edge.
     * @param oldWeight the old weight of the updated edge.
     * @param newWeight the new weight of the updated edge.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnUpdateEdgeWeight(Integer tailNode, 
                                                   Integer headNode, 
                                                   double oldWeight,
                                                   double newWeight) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onUpdateEdgeWeight(tailNode, 
                                        headNode, 
                                        oldWeight, 
                                        newWeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onRemoveNode} message to all the listeners.
     * 
     * @param node the removed node.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnRemoveNode(Integer node) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onRemoveNode(node);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onClearNode} message to all the listeners.
     * 
     * @param node the removed node.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnClearNode(Integer node) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onClearNode(node);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onRemoveEdge} message to all the listeners.
     * 
     * @param tailNodee the tail node of the removed edge.
     * @param headNode the head node of the removed edge.
     * @param weight the weight of the removed edge.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnRemoveEdge(Integer tailNodee, 
                                             Integer headNode, 
                                             double weight) {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onRemoveEdge(tailNodee, headNode, weight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the {@code onClearGraph} message to all the listeners.
     */
    protected void callListenerssOnClearGraph() {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onClearGraph();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates a message that any of the graph topology changed.
     */
    protected void callListenersOnAny() {
        for (GraphTopologyListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onAny();
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.impl.DirectedGraph.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a directed graph.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Jul 16, 2022)
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 11, 2016)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 11, 2016)
 */
public class DirectedGraph extends AbstractGraph {

    public static class Path {
        private final DirectedGraph ownerGraph;
        private final List<Integer> pathNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        private final double totalCost;

        public Path(DirectedGraph ownerGraph, List<Integer> pathNodes) {
            this.ownerGraph = ownerGraph;
            this.pathNodes.addAll(pathNodes);
            this.totalCost = computeTotalCost();
        }

        public Integer getNode(int index) {
            return pathNodes.get(index);
        }

        public double getTotalCost() {
            return totalCost;
        }

        private double computeTotalCost() {
            double totalCost = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < pathNodes.size() - 1; ++i) {
                totalCost = ownerGraph.getEdgeWeight(pathNodes.get(i),
                                                     pathNodes.get(i + 1));
            }

            return totalCost;
        }
    }

    private final Map<Integer, 
                      Map<Integer, 
                          Double>> parentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private final Map<Integer, 
                      Map<Integer, 
                          Double>> childMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();


    public DirectedGraph() {

    }

    /**
     * A copy constructor. The input graph remains intact.
     * 
     * @param graph the graph whose graph topology to assume. This includes the
     *              arc weights as well.
     */
    public DirectedGraph(DirectedGraph graph) {
        for (Integer node : graph.getAllNodes()) {
            parentMap.put(node, new HashMap<>());
            childMap.put(node, new HashMap<>());
        }

        for (Integer node : graph.getAllNodes()) {
            Map<Integer, Double> childrenMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map<Integer, Double> parentsMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (Integer child : graph.getChildrenOf(node)) {
                childrenMap.put(child, graph.getEdgeWeight(node, child));
            }

            childMap.get(node).putAll(childrenMap);

            for (Integer parent : graph.getParentsOf(node)) {
                parentsMap.put(parent, graph.getEdgeWeight(parent, node));
            }

            parentMap.get(node).putAll(parentsMap);
        }

        edges = graph.edges;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return parentMap.size();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int getNumberOfEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addNode(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);

        if (parentMap.containsKey(node)) {
            return false;
        }

        parentMap.put(node, new LinkedHashMap<>());
        childMap .put(node, new LinkedHashMap<>());
        callListenersOnAddNode(node);
        callListenersOnAny();
        modificationCount++;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNode(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);
        return parentMap.containsKey(node);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean clearNode(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);

        if (!hasNode(node)) {
            return false;
        }

        Map<Integer, Double> parents = parentMap.get(node);
        Map<Integer, Double> children = childMap.get(node);

        if (parents.isEmpty() && children.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Integer childId : children.keySet()) {
            parentMap.get(childId).remove(node);
        }

        for (Integer parentId : parents.keySet()) {
            childMap.get(parentId).remove(node);
        }

        int mod = parents.size() + children.size();
        edges -= mod;
        modificationCount++;
        callListenersOnClearNode(node);
        callListenersOnAny();
        parents.clear();
        children.clear();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeNode(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);

        if (!hasNode(node)) {
            return false;
        }

        clearNode(node);
        parentMap.remove(node);
        childMap.remove(node);
        callListenersOnRemoveNode(node);
        callListenersOnAny();
        modificationCount++;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addEdge(Integer tailNode,    
                           Integer headNode, 
                           double newWeight) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(tailNode);
        Objects.requireNonNull(headNode);

        addNode(tailNode);
        addNode(headNode);

        if (childMap.get(tailNode).containsKey(headNode)) {
            double oldWeight = childMap.get(tailNode).get(headNode);
            childMap.get(tailNode).put(headNode, newWeight);
            parentMap.get(headNode).put(tailNode, newWeight);

            if (oldWeight != newWeight) {
                modificationCount++;
                callListenersOnUpdateEdgeWeight(tailNode, 
                                                headNode, 
                                                oldWeight, 
                                                newWeight);
                callListenersOnAny();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        } else {
            childMap.get(tailNode).put(headNode, newWeight);
            parentMap.get(headNode).put(tailNode, newWeight);
            modificationCount++;
            edges++;
            callListenersOnAddEdge(tailNode, headNode, newWeight);
            callListenersOnAny();
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasEdge(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(tailNode);
        Objects.requireNonNull(headNode);

        if (!childMap.containsKey(tailNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        return childMap.get(tailNode).containsKey(headNode);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public double getEdgeWeight(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(tailNode);
        Objects.requireNonNull(headNode);

        if (!hasEdge(tailNode, headNode)) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }

        return childMap.get(tailNode).get(headNode);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeEdge(Integer tailNode, Integer headNode) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(tailNode);
        Objects.requireNonNull(headNode);

        if (!childMap.containsKey(tailNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!childMap.get(tailNode).containsKey(headNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        double weight = childMap.get(tailNode).get(headNode);
        childMap .get(tailNode).remove(headNode);
        parentMap.get(headNode).remove(tailNode);
        modificationCount++;
        edges--;
        callListenersOnRemoveEdge(tailNode, headNode, weight);
        callListenersOnAny();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getChildrenOf(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);

        if (!childMap.containsKey(node)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Node " + node + " is not in the graph.");
        }

        return Collections.
                <Integer>unmodifiableSet(childMap.get(node).keySet());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getParentsOf(Integer node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node);

        if (!parentMap.containsKey(node)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Node " + node + " is not in the graph.");
        }

        return Collections.
                <Integer>unmodifiableSet(parentMap.get(node).keySet());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getAllNodes() {
        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(childMap.keySet());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> entry : 
                childMap.entrySet()) {
            modificationCount += entry.getValue().size();
            entry.getValue().clear();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> entry :
                parentMap.entrySet()) {
            modificationCount += entry.getValue().size();
            entry.getValue().clear();
        }

        modificationCount += edges;
        childMap.clear();
        parentMap.clear();
        edges = 0;
        callListenerssOnClearGraph();
        callListenersOnAny();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.GraphTopologyListener.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph;

/**
 * This interface implements a graph topology listener.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 19, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 19, 2022)
 */
public interface GraphTopologyListener {

    /**
     * Called when adding a node to the owner graph.
     * 
     * @param node added node.
     */
    default void onAddNode(Integer node) {}

    /**
     * Called when adding an edge to the owner graph.
     * 
     * @param tail the tail node.
     * @param head the head node.
     * @param weight the edge weight.
     */
    default void onAddEdge(Integer tail, Integer head, double weight) {}

    /**
     * Called when the edge weight changed. This is called only when the old and 
     * the new weights are not equal.
     * 
     * @param tail      the tail node of the edge.
     * @param head      the head node of the edge.
     * @param oldWeight the old edge weight.
     * @param newWeight the new edge weight.
     */
    default void onUpdateEdgeWeight(Integer tail, 
                                    Integer head, 
                                    double oldWeight,
                                    double newWeight) {}

    /**
     * Called when a node is removed from the graph.
     * 
     * @param node the node to remove.
     */
    default void onRemoveNode(Integer node) {}

    /**
     * Called when a node is cleared from its incident edges.
     * 
     * @param node the node to clear.
     */
    default void onClearNode(Integer node) {}

    /**
     * Called when an edge is removed.
     * 
     * @param tail   the tail node of the removed edge.
     * @param head   the head node of the removed edge.
     * @param weight the weight of the removed edge.
     */
    default void onRemoveEdge(Integer tail, Integer head, double weight) {}

    /**
     * Called when the entire graph is cleared.
     */
    default void onClearGraph() {}

    /**
     * Called when any change in topology takes place.
     */
    default void onAny() {}
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: well - on Data structures there is not so much place for a review ^^ sadly that's all i found ^^ (but honestly: your code is always nice to read!!!)

Comment: @MartinFrank Thank you for your emotional support! It helps a lot! ^^

Answer (score 1):

### missing class `Node`

thats a major flaw since this kind of Graph forces you to use your predefined granularity of **Integers** - no chance ever to use a **Floating Point** value.

This implementation violates the [O principle of SOLID](https://stackify.com/solid-design-open-closed-principle/) (Open for change, closed for Manipulation).

### first class collection

mention in my answer from [Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278188/shortest-path-in-dags-part-2-3-the-preprocessing-and-shortest-path-algorithms) of your reviews

- `private final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> parentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();`
- `private final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> childMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

Comment: If I were to add a Node class, should it contain some satellite data?

Comment: nothing special, it only stores the costs